# HTTP Error on running ControlNet in Google Colab

Tags: artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion, image-generation, text2image

So, I'm installing stable diffusion with google colab Copy of fast_stable_diffusion_AUTOMATIC1111.ipynb - Colaboratory (google.com) and then running ControlNet (All 21GB), I'm getting this error message:

```
HTTPError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-740adf59b1eb> in <cell line: 72>()

72 if Model == "All (21GB)":

73 for lnk in mdllnk:

---> 74 download(lnk, mdldir)

75 clear_output()

76 7 frames/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs) 639 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):

640 def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs): --> 641 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

642

643 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler): HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Also this code line is underlined as error:

`download_url_to_file(url, pth, hash_prefix=None, progress=True)`

Please somebody fix this issue, I don't know much about tech.